# Using the !(not) operator when referring to a variable in a different class

Tags: c++, class

I have created an object from the class *HapticDevice* and would like to use the !(not) operator when referring to *device*, but this leads it to change the variable name. What to do guys

Example code:

```
            HapticsDevice haptic_device;
            if (haptic_device.!device.get()) return;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when referring to *device*"?  What is the type of `device`?

Comment: From your description, I'd guess `(!haptic_device.device).get()`, but that seems odd without knowing what device is.

Comment: do you want to negate the value returned from `get()` or do you want to negate `device` ? I suppose it is the first, but with operator overloading the second could be made to work as well. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your question is VERY unclear and, on the face of it, you are asking how to write an expression that would normally be a diagnosable error and suggesting it should be valid.  What type is `haptic.device`?    What do you expect the result of `haptic.!device` to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get `haptic_device.device`, NOT it, and then call `get` on the result of the not, it is `(!haptic_device.device).get()`. This is the same as `(!(haptic_device.device)).get()` since `.` has precedence over `!`. In fact, `.` has very high precedence.

I suspect you actually want `!haptic_device.device.get()` though which is the same as `!(haptic_device.device.get())` i.e. call `get()` and then call `!` on what `get()` returns.